# installing facebook sdk

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I am new to developing for android and i am having a problem installing the `facebook sdk`.

I have followed [this tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/%20this) and i am having a problem after `step 4`
when i try to run the app (*without changing my previously working code at all*) i am getting errors in the facebook [image: i added a picture]

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean facebook project. It can help.

Comment: i just got it, had to change the compiler compliance setting to 1.6